# How secure is flutter_secure_storage in Flutter?

Tags: security, flutter, storage

So I was looking for ways to implement persistent data storage in Flutter and came across quite a few of them, `flutter_secure_storage` being one of them. In my app, I am going to make API calls to give me the distance and duration between two latitude and longitude coordinates. And I don't want to make the calls too often as the coordinates won't change for quite a long while, so I want to persist the data.

For the authentication, I am using Firebase. But my question is, is `flutter_secure_storage` secure enough to store data as it is? Or should I use some further String encryption stuff before storing it as a key: value pair?

Or is there a better alternative? Cause I found the secure_storage extremely easy to implement in code than `sqflite`.

Also, I am prioritizing security because the app will be released to a 'wide number' of people.

Comment: Secure enough.
But to be honest - that is not a SOF question. Ask package's author about this.

Comment: Yes it is secured. If device is android then flutter_secure_storage library store data in encryptedSharedPreference which is android specific shared prference where key values store in encrypted format. 
If deice is iOS then flutter_secure_storage library store data in Keychain which is iOS specific storage where key values store in encrypted format and which is accessible only by your app.